# Use External Access Token or Local Access Token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-identity, owin

I am developing an application using `ASP.NET MVC 5.2.2, Web API 2.2 and Katana/OWIN 3.0`. The application uses ASP.NET Identity 2.1 for local accounts and database.

I am using [OAuth Authorization Server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server) to generate access and refresh token. I have Android and IOS apps which uses my local oauth authorization server. Android and IOS apps uses SDK to login with Facebook, Google, etc. After that the apps will send the (Facebook/Google/etc) access token to the server. The server will validate access token with Facebook/Google/etc.

If it is valid then,

> 1) Should I generate new local access token(in Auth header) to apps
>   for all future request?
>
> 2) Should the app send me Facebook/Gmail/etc
>   access token(in Auth header) every time and the server validate the
>   access token with Facebook/Gmail/etc each time?
>
> 3) If local access
>   token expire, then the server is using refresh token to generate new
>   access token. Should the server update the access token as well as
>   refresh token during this time or updating access token is enough?

Comment: As I understand, you are authenticating your Android/iOS apps to Google/Facebook. After receiving access_token from these third party services, your server will validate the token again with Google/Facebook. Then, what is the purpose of this second validation? Is it working (server validating the Android/Facebook access token  to Google/Facebook)? I've never tried, but It's quite strange for me to understand, taking in consideration how access token are created.

Comment: @Freerider, I am using OAUTH Server(see link above) with Bearer Authentication. When user logins I need to generate an access token from my oauth server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

after you validate your social provider external access token, you need to exchange this external access token with a local access token issued by your authorization server (Local authority). All the details for this implementation can be found here: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/ 
Let me know if this helps.

Here is the exact steps I have followed to change the external access token with access token issues by Local Authority. The front end is an AngularJS application. You can check the demo application here and see how I'm accessing the web api using Facebook access token http://ngauthenticationweb.azurewebsites.net/

1- AngularJS application sends HTTP GET request to anonymous end point (/ExternalLogin) defined in our back-end API by specifying client_id, redirect_uri, response_type.

2- Once the end point receives the GET request, it will check if the user is authenticated, and let we assume he is not authenticated, so it will notify the middleware responsible for the requested external provider to take the responsibility for this call, in our case it is Google.

3- The consent screen for Google will be shown, and the user will provide his Google credentials to authenticate.

4- Google will callback our back-end API and Google will set an external cookie containing the outcome of the authentication from Google (contains all the claims from the external provider for the user).

5- Google middleware will be listing for an event named “Authenticated” where we’ll have the chance to read all external claims set by Google. In our case we’ll be interested in reading the claim named “AccessToken” which represents a Google Access Token, where the issuer for this claim is not LOCAL AUTHORITY, so we can’t use this access token directly to authorize calls to our secure back-end API endpoints.

6- Then we’ll set the external provider external access token as custom claim named “ExternalAccessToken” and Google middleware will redirect back the end point (/ExternalLogin).

7- Now the user is authenticated using the external cookie so we need to check that the client_id and redirect_uri set in the initial request are valid and this client is configured to redirect for the specified URI.

8- Now the code checks if the external user_id along with the provider is already registered as local database account (with no password), in both cases the code will issue 302 redirect to the specified URI in the redirect_uri parameter, this URI will contain the following (“External Access Token”, “Has Local Account”, “Provider”, “External User Name”) as URL hash fragment not a query string.

9- Once the AngularJS application receives the response, it will decide based on it if the user has local database account or not, based on this it will issue a request to one of the end points (/RegisterExternal or /ObtainLocalAccessToken). Both end points accept the external access token which will be used for verification and then using it to obtain local access token issued by LOCAL AUTHORITY. This local access token could be used to access our back-end API secured end points.

Comment: I agree with this. To #3 the answer is little trickier. Oauth flows for mobile don't include refresh tokens so whether you use a bearer token or the access token really doesn't help you. You may have to build something into your protocol to work in a new bearer token.

Comment: I am using Native mobile? Come-on

Comment: It is the same, seems you are not reading the answer properly. with this approach you will exchange the external access token you get from the SDK with access token issued by local authority. Good luck.

Comment: The mobile is the responsible for getting the Facebook access token and the server will validate and generate an access token. This is fine but but ho do I get refresh token explicitly. I am marking this as answer but still this is not an answer.