# Refresh local access tokens for social logins in OWIN OAuth2

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, owin

I am using OAuth2 included in OWIN for authentication. The system issues local access tokens to clients no matter whether they are using locally created accounts or social logins.

[The tutorial I have been following](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/) works fine so far. Now, I am testing the functionality for handling unauthorized requests due to expired local access tokens. For users having their accounts that are created locally, the unauthorized requests can be re-sent by carrying out the following steps in the client application:

1. refresh access token by sending a request to the server
2. retrieve the newly generated access token and update the one in local storage
3. re-send the previous unauthorized request

However, the aforementioned steps cannot be applied to accounts created via social logins. The code snippet below is the entry point of the entire social login routine in my AngularJS application.

```
// provider is a string like "facebook" or "google"
var externalProviderUrl = (
    "http://www.example.com/api/account/externallogin?provider=" + provider +
    "&response_type=token&client_id=" + clientId +
    "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri
);
window.$windowScope = $scope;
var oauthWindow = window.open(externalProviderUrl, "Authentication", "location=0,status=0,width=1024,height=800");
```

As a large piece of code is involved in the whole social login routine, I am not posting it here. Readers may refer to the tutorial linked above. What the routine does is explained in the answer of this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665566/use-external-access-token-or-local-access-token).

What the tutorial does not cover is how the local access tokens issued to social login accounts can be refreshed. My authentication server can now only refresh local access tokens for locally created accounts.

I have tried to replicate such situation in the [demo site](http://ngauthenticationweb.azurewebsites.net/#/home) made by the author of the tutorial. The way he handles it is to send the user back to the login page.

Is it possible to refresh local access tokens for social login users automatically?